# Space between text and border

Tags: html, css

I used padding-top to make space between li and its border but it move all the navbar place.

Is there anyway to make space without moving it ?

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 2.5%;
  padding: 0.5%;
}
nav li a {
  color: #646464;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li.active,
nav li:hover {
  border-top: 3px solid #f0842a;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link3">LINK 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#link4">LINK 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link5">LINK 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it move all the navbar place`. What is the desired effect?

Comment: I just want to make space between the border and the text without moving the nav down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a Margin of -20px to the .nav will cancel out the drop.

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 2.5%;
  padding: 0.5%;
}
nav li a {
  color: #646464;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li.active,
nav li:hover {
  border-top: 3px solid #f0842a;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link3">LINK 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#link4">LINK 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link5">LINK 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It solved the problem, but i'm wondering if using a negative margin is a proper way?

Comment: @obk I have used it in many of my projects, its a simple fix and have never had any issues with it.

Comment: @WilliamBargent  i would like to suggest you that generally use of negative margin is bad habit so try to avoid it as possible as you can

Answer (score 2):

You can use `margin-top` of `10px` and `padding-top` of `10px`. This will keep the dimensions of the element same, and the border will be closer to the text.

Using this, the `li` elements are having total space of `20px` on their top.

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 2.5%;
  padding: 0.5%;
}
nav li a {
  color: #646464;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li.active,
nav li:hover {
  border-top: 3px solid #f0842a;
  padding-top: 10px; /* Use 10px; here */
  margin-top: 10px; /* Use 10px; here */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link3">LINK 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#link4">LINK 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link5">LINK 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the desired effect is when active class applied to one of the menu items and not shift the menu you should have a boarder top for each list item with same width but transparent or same as background color, and when the class active applied it would only change the color of this border.

Answer (score 0):

> using **negative margin is  i think a bad habit** that is my thought and i
>   have read in many articles as well and as per your accepted answer
>   there is another way to achieve this thing and here that i have give

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: right;
}
nav ul{
  margin-top: 0;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 2.5% 2.5% 2.5%;
    padding: 0.5%;
}
nav li a {
  color: #646464;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li.active,
nav li:hover {
  border-top: 3px solid #f0842a;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link3">LINK 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#link4">LINK 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link5">LINK 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and here is the demo working code

[Check Out](https://jsfiddle.net/c0teL0c6/)

---

**[Actual Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c0teL0c6/2/)**

Comment: @obk please check out you can achieve this another way

Comment: it does not work as i'm looking.. the negative margin give a better result

Comment: @obk hi actually by mistake i updated previous demo so that was not worked so now now edited actual one you can see that it is working

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav{
  float:right;
  width:80%;
  font-size:80%;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
}
nav li a{
  color: #646464;
  font-weight: bold;                
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;

}
nav li.active,
nav li:hover{
  border-top-color:#f0842a;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link3">LINK 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#link4">LINK 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link5">LINK 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```